# Not able to copy/paste using xclip from Vmware Kali Guest's terminal to Debian 10 Host's terminal

Tags: linux, debian, vmware, copy, paste

I can't copy/paste between host and guest terminals when using xclip. Is it possible? or do I need another solution to copy/paste between command lines of VM's and Hosts?